# Dynamically formatting individual axis labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This may end up being an `expression` or `call` question, but I am trying to conditionally format individual axis labels.

In the following example, I'd like to selectively bold one of the axis labels:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(labs = c("Oranges", "Apples", "Cucumbers"), counts = c(5, 10, 12))

ggplot(data = data) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = labs, y = counts), stat="identity")`
```

[image: No Bolding]

There is similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609716/changing-format-of-some-axis-labels-in-ggplot2-according-to-condition), but the solution involves `theme` and `element_text`. I am trying to use axis labels directly.

I can do this manually as below:

```
breaks <- levels(data$labs)
labels <- breaks
labels[2] <- expression(bold("Cucumbers"))

ggplot(data = data) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = labs, y = counts), stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(label = labels, breaks = breaks)
```

[image: Bolded]

But, if I try to do it by indexing instead of typing out "Cucumbers", I get the following error:

```
breaks <- levels(data$labs)
labels <- breaks
labels[2] <- expression(bold(labels[2]))

ggplot(data = data) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = labs, y = counts), stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(label = labels, breaks = breaks)
```

[image]

Which makes sense, because it is not evaluating the `labels[2]`. But, does anyone know how to force it to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about

```
breaks <- levels(data$labs)
labels <- as.expression(breaks)
labels[[2]] <- bquote(bold(.(labels[[2]])))

ggplot(data = data) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = labs, y = counts), stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(label = labels, breaks = breaks)
```

Here we are more explicit about the conversion to expression and we use `bquote()` to insert the value of the label into the expression itself.

Comment: Yes! `bquote` and `.( )` were what I needed. Thanks. 

Is there a mnemonic for that function name? Backwards quote?

Comment: From the help page, it's "an analogue of the LISP backquote macro" so that's pretty close.

Comment: @MrFlick How could I do this for multiple items? For example for position 2 and 3? And also could I do this by specifying the factor names, e.g. "Cucumbers" and "Oranges"? Thanks!

Comment: @Stefan You might want to ask a new question with a reproducible example that says how your case is different. `labels` basically asks like a list so you can use any of the functions you use to iterate over lists. The order of the labels goes in the order of the breaks so you can look up values in one and index in the other without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to set the font face dynamically with `theme`, though I'm not sure if this is in any sense a better or worse method than @MrFlick's answer:

```
breaks <- levels(data$labs)

# Reference breaks by name
toBold = "Cucumbers"

ggplot(data = data) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = labs, y = counts), stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(label = labels, breaks = breaks) +
  theme(axis.text.x=
        element_text(face=ifelse(breaks %in% toBold, "bold", "plain")))

# Reference breaks by position
label.index=2

ggplot(data = data) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = labs, y = counts), stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(label = labels, breaks = breaks) +
  theme(axis.text.x=
        element_text(face=ifelse(breaks %in% labels[match(label.index, 1:length(breaks))], 
                                 "bold", "plain")))
```