# Programatically set axis face in ggplots with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

If one tries to programmatically set the font face for axis labels, one process works in the absence of facets but breaks when facets are present. For instance

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

data("mtcars")

mtcars  %<>% 
  rownames_to_column %>% 
  mutate(
    rowname = rowname %>% 
      fct_reorder(mpg)
  )


p1 <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(mpg, rowname)
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(
      face = c("plain", "bold") %>% 
        rep(c(30, 2))
      )
    )

p1
```

Returns

[image: plain and bold labels]

But if I add facets, this pattern of plain and bold y-axis labels is lost

```
p1 + 
  facet_grid(
    cyl ~ .,
    scales = "free_y",
    space = "free_y"
    )
```

[image: no plain and bold labels]

How can I embolden some labels in the presence of `facet_grid`?

Comment: Maybe related: [ggplot2: Coloring axis text on a faceted plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843759/ggplot2-coloring-axis-text-on-a-faceted-plot)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a workaround but you should have no problem implementing it in your case. I toyed around with it a bit and had better luck creating an actual fontface variable right in the dataset and using numerics, instead of `c("plain", "bold")`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

data("mtcars")

mtcars  %<>% 
  rownames_to_column %>% 
  mutate(
    rowname = rowname %>% 
      fct_reorder(mpg)
  )

mtcars$font_face <- rep(c(1,2,3,4))

p1 <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, rowname)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = mtcars$font_face)) +
  facet_grid(cyl ~ .,
             scales = "free_y",
             space = "free_y")


p1
```

[image]

As you can see, the positions of the four faces are italic=1, bold=2, plain=3, and bold.italic=4.

So to recreate the example as you've presented, you just need to generate a variable in the original data piping and assign it using whatever relevant method. To recreate your example explicitly I'd go with the following code but I assume you'll want to work up a dplyr solution that actually fits your use case.

```
mtcars$font_face <- ifelse(mtcars$rowname %in% c("Toyota Corolla", "Fiat 128"), 2, 3)
```

## edit:

The final solution is currently not working (the `ifelse` line). It recognizes the `else` value and selecting among `1:4` successfully changes the effect applied to the labels, but it doesn't pick change the labels for the `if` values, despite the fact that the `mtcars$font_face` variable does take on those values.

I'm stuck at the moment because I can't figure out why it ran for me before but not on a fresh session. I'm still working on figuring it out myself but perhaps my start can help someone to get to the next step.

Comment: This actually doesn't work for me, or even for the example set out in the question, in that, if you tried to use the `ifelse` statement and then plotted with `facet_grid`, all the labels are italicized

Comment: You're right. I had it working originally, but I just retried on a fresh session and it can't recreate it. I'll keep playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

This question has a hacky answer that nonetheless seems to work well for your problem: [ggplot2: Coloring axis text on a faceted plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843759/ggplot2-coloring-axis-text-on-a-faceted-plot).

To adapt this to your problem, we have to move the fake axis to the y-axis and tweak the settings to make it look good with your data's labels.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

data("mtcars")

mtcars  %<>% 
    rownames_to_column %>% 
    mutate(
        rowname = rowname %>% 
            fct_reorder(mpg),
        font_face = as.factor(if_else(rowname %in% c("Toyota Corolla", "Fiat 128"), 'bold', 'plain'))
    )

mtcars %>% 
    ggplot(aes(mpg, rowname)) +
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(cyl ~ .,
               scales = "free_y",
               space = "free_y") +
    # make space to accommodate the fake axis
    expand_limits(x = -5) +
    # create a strip of white background under the fake axis
    geom_rect(xmin = -20, xmax = 0, ymin = 0, ymax = nrow(mtcars) + 1, fill = "white") +
    # fake axis layer
    geom_text(aes(fontface = font_face, label = rowname), x = -.2, vjust = .5, hjust = 1, size = 3)  + 
    # hide the actual axis text / ticks
    theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

[image: Plot with appropriate row labels shown in bold]